# Trying to change transform variable in script but it is returning an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing this in Unity.

I'm attempting to detect a player hitting a 2D trigger on a sprite and then disabling the player(making him become invisible) and then having the camera follow the ship instead of the player.

My trouble is when the code reaches

```
 Camera.target = Ship;
```

it returns this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

I have already checked and made certain that the objects I'm trying to assign to variables are properly named and exist. I'm unsure however, if I am correctly assigning them or setting them to variables.

```
public class EnterShip : MonoBehaviour {

    object Player;
    public Transform Ship;
    CameraScript Camera;

    private void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        Ship = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
        Camera = GetComponent<CameraScript>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == ("Player")) 
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Camera.target = Ship;  //Changing Target variable to the ships transform
        }

    }
}

public class CameraScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;   //Main Camera will follow whatever this is
    Vector3 PlrPos;



    void Update ()
    {

        PlrPos = target.position;
    }
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = PlrPos + new Vector3(0f, 0f, -10f); //offset
    }
}
```

Comment: `Camera` is `null`.

Comment: You've assigned a value with `GetComponent<CameraScript>()`, but you haven't validated that the return of that call isn't null.